# php PDO how to calculate inside the class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is the form:

```
<form>
<input type='text' value='10' name='counting'/>
<input type='text' value='10' name='new'/>
<input type='text' value='5' name='return'/>
<input tyep='submit' value='update'/>
</form>
```

now on update here it must update the , **counting** and **new** which will minis the number of **return** from both.

this is the class where the action will take place:

```
            $id = 1;

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET counting =:counting, new =:new WHERE id =:id LIMIT 1"); 
            $counting = ($this->counting - $this->return);
            $new =      ($this->new - $this->return);                                                    
            $stmt->bindParam(':counting' , $counting);
            $stmt->bindParam(':new' ,      $new);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id' ,        $id);
            $stmt->execute();
```

Problem is on

```
               $counting = ($this->counting - $this->return);
                $new =      ($this->new - $this->return);
```

the error is ( **object of class X could not conver to int** && **Undefined constant return** ))
how i can have such mathematical operation in PDO class.

regards

Comment: "Not working" is pretty vague. Does it show you an error/white screen, does it insert wrong values, what? In addition, where's the code that populates `$this->counting` and other values for your math operations?

Comment: Run `var_dump($this->counting, $this->new, $this->return, $this);` before the error line, look at the output. Does it show the values you expect? Check for typos, the error message suggests you might have some mistypes in the `->return` part. And you did not show the code that loads the input values into that object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the value of the input is a string. Use either the (int) or (integer) casts to convert it. ie:

```
$countring = (int) $this->counting;
$new = (int) $this->new;
```

see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting).